# Z3 invalid function app, args missing

Tags: z3

it's my first time using `Z3` and im trying to find all the sat truth assignments for the given form, it keeps throwing:

`Z3(5, 10): ERROR: invalid function application, arguments missing`

```
(echo "((p => q) v (q => p)) ^ ~((p => q) ^ (q => p)))")
(declare-const p Bool)
(declare-const q Bool)
(assert (and(or(=> p q)(=> q p)) (not(and(=> p q) (=> q p)))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
(assert (or (=> p q)(=> qp)))
(assert (not(and(=> p q) (=> q p)))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need more of those right parentheses.

```
(echo "((p => q) v (q => p)) ^ ~((p => q) ^ (q => p)))")
(declare-const p Bool)
(declare-const q Bool)
(assert (and(or(=> p q)(=> q p)) (not(and(=> p q) (=> q p)))))
(check-sat)

(get-model)
(assert (or (=> p q)(=> q p)))
(assert (not(and(=> p q) (=> q p))))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Thank you.